# How to run a trivial ZIO for comprehension snippet

Tags: zio

In the getstarted zio doc page there is this [trivial exemple](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_basic_operations#for-comprehensions), but I cannot run it, what could be a simple code to make this snippet work (have a question and be able to answer in the console) ?

```
import zio.console.{getStrLn, putStrLn}
object Bug41 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Start")
    val program =
      for {
        _    <- putStrLn("Hello! What is your name?")
        name <- getStrLn
        _    <- putStrLn(s"Hello, ${name}, welcome to ZIO!")
      } yield ()
    program.run
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
import zio._
import zio.console._
import zio.internal.Platform

object Logic {
  val main: RIO[Console, Unit] =
    for {
      _    <- console.putStrLn("Hello! What is your name?")
      name <- console.getStrLn
      _    <- console.putStrLn(s"Hello, $name, welcome to ZIO!")
    } yield ()
}

object Bug41 extends zio.App {
  def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = Logic.main.exitCode

  override val platform: Platform = Platform.default.withReportFailure(println)
}
```

Comment: Merged previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
object Bug41 {

  val program: RIO[Console, Unit] =
    for {
      _    <- putStrLn("Hello! What is your name?")
      name <- getStrLn
      _    <- putStrLn(s"Hello, $name, welcome to ZIO!")
    } yield ()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val runtime: Runtime[zio.ZEnv] = zio.Runtime.default.mapPlatform(_.withReportFailure(cause => println(cause)))

    runtime.unsafeRun(program)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interacting with ZIO you can use the built-in `zio.App` instead

```
object Bug41 extends zio.App {
  def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = 
    (for {
      _    <- putStrLn("Hello! What is your name?")
      name <- getStrLn
      _    <- putStrLn(s"Hello, $name, welcome to ZIO!")
    } yield ()).exitCode
}
```

This way you can push everything to the end of the world and handle errors cleanly.